# Interfacing an MSP430g2553 with a 16x4 LCD screen

Tags: msp430, lcd

I'm having trouble getting my msp430 to communicate with a 16x4 LCD screen.  Data sheet for the LCD screen: https://www.beta-estore.com/download/rk/RK-10290_410.pdf

Here is my code:

```
#define READMODE P2OUT = (P2OUT | BIT1) //set R/W pin high
#define WRITEMODE P2OUT=(P2OUT & ~BIT1) //set R/W pin low
#define ENABLEON P2OUT=P2OUT | 0x04 //set enable pin high
#define ENABLEOFF P2OUT=P2OUT & 0xFB //set enable pin low
#define RSDATA P2OUT = (P2OUT | BIT0) //set register select bit high so that the databus is sent to display
#define RSINSTRUCTION P2OUT = (P2OUT & ~BIT0) //set register select low so databus is sent to command register for initialization
int main(void){
  WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD; //stop watchdog timer
  P1DIR = 0xFF;  //The entire P1 register is output
  P2DIR = 0xF7; //The entire P2 register is output except for p2.3
  P1OUT = 0x00;
  P2OUT = 0x01;
  ENABLEOFF;
  WRITEMODE;
  RSINSTRUCTION;
  sendCommand(0x30); //function set for 8 bit mode and display type
  sendCommand(0x01); //clear screen
  sendCommand(0x02); //Return Home
  sendCommand(0x07); //Increment cursor and screen right
  sendCommand(0x0B); //Screen display on and blinking cursor
  sendChar('a');
}

/**This function checks if the LCD is busy
 */
void isBusy(void){
  P1DIR &= ~BIT7; //Set bit 7 of P1 register as input
  READMODE;
  RSINSTRUCTION;
  while((P1IN & BIT7) == BIT7){
    dataRead();
  }
  P1DIR |= BIT7; //Set bit 7 of P1 register back to output 
  WRITEMODE;
}

/**Allows databus to be sent to LCD 
 */
void dataWrite(void){
  ENABLEOFF;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
  ENABLEON;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
  ENABLEOFF;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
}

/**This function is only for checking if the LCD is busy.  If it is busy 
 * it will blink the enable light on and off
 */
void dataRead(void){
  ENABLEOFF;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
  ENABLEON;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
  ENABLEOFF;
  __delay_cycles(1000000);
}

/**This function sends a command to the LCD screen
 */
void sendCommand(unsigned char command){
  isBusy();
  WRITEMODE;
  RSINSTRUCTION;
  P1OUT = command;
  dataWrite();
}

void sendChar(char letter){
  RSDATA;
  WRITEMODE;
  P1OUT = letter;
  dataWrite();
}
```

I'm pretty positive all my pins are connected correctly.  The LCD is projecting light but that's it.  I can't even get the cursor to show up and blink on the screen.  I have my bus connected to 8 LED lights so I can be sure the correct commands are being sent.  That is also why I have the long delay in between each write operation.  Not sure what to do from here to troubleshoot. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you don't try to send a character but just stop after the last sendCommand?

Comment: Nothing. The LCD screen is on but there is no blinking cursor

Comment: I decided to drag out my old 20x4 display and give it a go. Currently I can't get anything to show up either. :-) I'll keep you posted.

Comment: Did you add a potentiometet to the LCD Drive Voltage V0 to adjust the contrast? See section 8.1 of the DataSheet,

Comment: No, I did not. It is at a constant 3.3 V. I figured that was OK since the pin only effects contrast

Comment: Yes, but the contrast is your problem. I think so. Cause there is no blinking cursor.  ;-). Please give it  try. I think you have white characters on white background.

Comment: Ah, OK. I will try tonight and update

Comment: Ahh... , the data sheet contains an error in section 8.1. If you add the potentiometer, please do not connect +5V/3.6V (VDD) an GND (VSS) as they show. They made a mistake that could destroy your power supply.

Comment: Are you sure? I thought VDD and VSS was for the logic of the circuit. Not the actual display.

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer is referring to how the diagram shows a direct connection from Vdd to ground at the right hand side. That is a direct short.

Comment: @HeadCode Thank you! That's exactly what I tried to say. But I'm not a native english speaker. And have not much practise.   user3736114 Did you try to use a potentionmeter.

Comment: The potentiometer made a difference.  I can now see the rows and seperate cells very clearly.  The LCD still seems unresponsive though.  No blinking cursor still.  Could there be something wrong with the LCD screen?

Comment: NEVERMIND! It works! I changed a command previously that turned the display off. After changing that it worked as expected.  So the solution to the original question was the potentiometer.  If you comment again I will mark it as solution.  Thank you @PeterPaulKiefer

Comment: Would you mind either posting the final solution or making an edit to show the exact initialization commands that actually worked?

Comment: You are welcome! I could enter an answer which you can mark as the solution. But my answer is only one part of the solution. You also changed the command that turned the display off. Therefor it would be great if you answer your question youselve. You could mention my solution of using a potentionmeter and also your changes. That would be fine for me. After a short time you could mark your answer as the accepted one. I will also vote you question up. Cheers PPK.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay.  The solution to the issue was adding a potentiometer to the circuit so I could change the contrast of the LCD.  I also had to change the line

```
sendCommand(0x0B); //Screen display on and blinking cursor
```

to

```
sendCommand(0x0F); //Screen display on and blinking cursor
```

Thank you all for the contributions.